# Python Coding - Using Spyder or Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, spyder

First of all, I am no programming expert. Zero experience, however, I am interested in learning it.

Summarize the problem.
My Master's topic requires me to use machine learning to predict if current hard engineering structures (concrete seawalls, gabions, etc...) are capable of withstanding future sea-level rise by the year 2071.
I managed to download the following:
-tide gauge data (1973-2021)
-gridded satellite altimetry data (1993-2022)

If I am to do future predictions, it will be as such:
-tide guage data from the years 1973-2021-2071
-gridded satellite altimetry from the years 1993-2021-2071

Essentially, my prediction involves 50 years into the future

Describe what you’ve tried.
Tried countless things - I don't even know where to start from haha. I tried searching youtube videos, stack overflow examples, and general sites on google, but nothing that can help me with my specific problem. I guess my problem is that I DO NOT know how to link one sentence code to another such that it becomes error-free. I managed to get hold of this website from a friend of mine.
In other words, I need help or guidance from someone who is well versed with python and machine learning - it would mean the whole world to me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this is a time series regression task

Comment: Unfortunately, you've come to a site that is not geared toward guidance and comprehensive advice, but instead focuses on specific, well-scoped questions. I hope you have better luck elsewhere.